# Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, microsoft-office-365

I have an issue where a new mailbox in Exchange Online is reporting Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender when sending mail from an app server.

using these settings, values changed for security:

```
<mailSettings>
      <smtp from="mailbox@domain.com">
      <network host="ipaddress" port="25" userName="mailbox@domain.com" password="password" defaultCredentials="false" />
     </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

Do you have any ideas what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Which type mentioned in the [guidance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365) do you use to send mails through app server?

Check the guidance and make sure the prerequisites are configured correctly and then check if this issue continues. Here's a screenshot on comparing these 3 methods for your reference and it will be helpful for you to choose the better method:[image]